# Webform form submit, and notify auto email in html format!

Tags: drupal, webform-civicrm

I have a newsletter signup form built over webform. For people who signed up, I want to send an automatic notifications email once the form is submitted. It's working like a plain text. But I would like to customise the email and send in html format. Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can! You'll need some more Drupal modules/ config - here is a pretty good tutorial: https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/html-emails-from-drupal-webform/

Note (if this was re: Contribution, Membership or Events): webform_civicrm module will also check to see if you have the Thank you and Receipting section filled out on your CiviCRM side - get into your message templates (HTML version) to make edits to that - if you go that route!

Comment: Note that you also have to go to /admin/config/content/webform and enable HTML email in the settings there as well (this is noted in the comments on the post linked above, but not in the actual post, which left me scratching my head).

Comment: thanks Lars SG. I was also wondering why it wasn't effective.